# run laravel project under addon domain

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, addon-domain

I have a addon domain in cpanel for my website : "siteB" which are hosted under a shared hosting with this structure:

```
var/home/siteA
   ->public_html (main domain 'siteA')
   ->siteB.com (addon domain)
        ->public (for siteB)
        ->app
        ->vendor
        -> ...
```

the addon domain name has a laravel website which is perfectly working on the local host. so i make a public folder in siteB and i have copied all the files and upload them to the addon domain and also imported the database and made the changes on the env file.

When i enter 'www.siteB.com' in the browser, first page run correctly but i cant access to another route in my project.

I think its related to the document_root that i have to change it for addon domain. but cant do anything.

How can i fixed this problem with addon domain project?

Comment: What is an "addon domain"? I presume it's a term from some sort of control panel like cPanel, Plesk, etc. It's fairly important you say which.

Comment: i edited my question, addon domain in cpanel host for my new app

Comment: If you are using cpanel, then cpanel will automatically generate a folder for your subdomain,

Comment: siteB folder has been generated for me by cpanel  when i add new addon domain for my new website 'siteB.com' and i try tu run my laravel app on this domain, i copy laravel file into that base on above structure and i can just see my first page(index) on mu site and any other route i goT i get 404 error that even does not related to the laravel app